# xfce4-display-settings minimal dialog does not show "extend to the right" option

Tags: debian, xfce, multi-monitor

Using Mint Qiana with xfce, to configure multi display, when the proper shortcut buttons are pressed, in the screen appears a window with some display options, including "extend desktop to the right".

Unfortunately, in the same notebook, when using xfce on Debian 8, after pressing the proper shortcut button, there appears a window to select the multi display configuration, but without the option to "extend desktop to the right".

What is the problem with xfce4-display-settings on Debian?